# Question About Orthoganality of Hermite Polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, orthogonality

It is known that is $m \ne n$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H_n(x) H_m(x) e^{-x^2}dx = 0
$$

Does this apply for any $f(x)$?

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H_n(f(x)) H_m(f(x)) e^{f(x)^2} dx = 0
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it has to be $e^{x^2}$. It wont work for even $e^{x^2}/2$.

In your case, you would need to substitute $f(x)$ so you would need to multiply by $f'(x)$ as well. Then it would work.

Of course if you end up with an odd integrand, it will always be 0, that should be kept in mind.

Comment: Do you mind showing me what would work?

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } 2 e^{-x^4} x H_2\left(x^2\right) H_4\left(x^2\right) \, dx=0$$

Comment: Lets say i have an arbitrary $f(x)$, how would you determine its orthogonality?

Comment: Would it be:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x) e^{-x^2f(x)} H_n(x)H_m(x) dx = 0
$$

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }  e^{-f (x)^2}  H_m(f (x)) H_n(f (x)) f'(x)\, dx$$

Comment: Oh okay, thanks!