# orthogonality of hermite polynomials when $x \rightarrow f(x)$

Tags: calculus, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

We know that if $m \ne n$:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}H_n(x)H_m(x)dx = 0
$$

And

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} H_n(x)^2dx = \delta_{nm} 2^n n! \sqrt{\pi}
$$

Now I am trying to find this when $x \rightarrow f(x)$ therefore I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324606/question-about-orthoganality-of-hermite-polynomials) that when $m \ne n$:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x) e^{-f(x)^2}H_n(f(x))H_m(f(x))dx = 0
$$

Now i am trying to find what this is equal to:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)e^{-f(x)^2}H_n(f(x))^2dx = ?
$$

Also i am having a bit of trouble when finding the following:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}(4x^2-2)^2 dx = 0
$$

But shouldn't it be equal to some numerical value due to the orthogonal property it holds?

Comment: Well even if it didnt have to satisfy an orthogonality condition, the integrand in that last part is a symmetric function in x and is essentially positive  save for the roots of the quartic polynomial, it doesnt look like it should be zero no

Comment: @Dan http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+-infinity+to+infinity+of+e%5E%28-x%5E2%29%284x%5E2-2%29

Comment: I cant see what you posted there based on formatting of the link

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Hermite polynomials form a complete orthogonal set for
$\mathcal{L}^2[-\infty,\infty]$. This means we can expand a function
$f(x)$ in this basis.

Your first question is about finding the projection of $f'(x)$ on this space.
There is no short cut. You have to do the integral. This is similar to
finding Fourier coefficients.

With that, let me address your second question. Note that the integral is zero if $m\neq n$. In this case, $m=n=2$.
Using the identity , we obtain:
$$
2^{2}\sqrt{\pi}2!=8\sqrt{\pi}
$$

Comment: But wolframalpha says it should be zero:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+-infinity+to+infinity+of+e%5E%28-x%5E2%29%284x%5E2-2%29

Comment: @Eric, you forgot to square H_2. I don't get zero. integral from -infinity to infinity of e^(-x^2)(4x^2-2)^2